# Clickable table rows linked to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

My MVC 4 project has a table of information and right now I am using two input boxes for the user to enter the PolicyId (One of the fields on my table) and then I use the PolicyIds to select the policies and send them into my view to compare them.

I have read up on clickable table rows, but mostly saw people making a single select-able table row that opens a link.

I would like to make my table to allow me to select two rows and then click a button to compare the rows in more detail.

So I would like it to grab the PolicyId for each selected row so I can pass them into my MVC view that is set up for my deeper comparison.

I saw some people talk about using checkboxes, but most of the implementations I saw were very glitchy.

From my research, most people seem to be going the jQuery/javascript route. I am new to web programming and only have HTML and CSS experience. So if anyone knows any good references on how to do this in the most basic way possible(jQuery/javascript OK, if not too complex) or takes on how to use an entire row as text box and store the results or any other creative solutions, it would be appreciated! Thanks!

**Here is some of my code snippets from my html file:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FindPolicyRequests", "RequestResponse", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ServiceRequestResponseETO" }))
{    
     <div style="float: left;">
       Insurance Policy Identifier: @Html.TextBox("polId")<input class="findbutton" id="findExecute" type="submit" value="Find" />
     </div> 
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SrrCompare", "RequestResponse", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ServiceRequestResponseETO" }))
{    


    <div style="float: right; width: auto;">
          <b style="text-align: left; float: left;">Compare Responses:</b>
          <b style="text-align: left; float: left;">SRR Identifier 1:</b> @Html.TextBox("polId1")<br />
           SRR Identifier 2: @Html.TextBox("polid2")
           <input class="findbutton" type="submit" value="Compare" />
    </div> 
}

.
.
.

<table class="srrTable">
                    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                        <th>PolicyId
                        </th>
                        <th>DataText
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PolicyId)
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataText)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
```

Comment: Could you provide us w/ some code you've already written?

Comment: @KyleDecot i added what I have currently for selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adds the policyId of the targeted row to an array. Watch it in Firebug, I hope it helps.

```
(function($) {

  var $table = $(document.getElementById('data')),
      policyIds = [];

  $table.on('click', 'tr', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    policyIds.push(parseInt($this.find('td:nth-child(1)').text(), 10));

    console.log(policyIds);

  });

})(jQuery);
```

http://jsbin.com/iquvab/1/

Updated with toggle functionality, see http://jsbin.com/akudex/1/edit

Comment: Updated so that it's possible to toggle click a row without getting multiple ID's of the same row.